# How to structure selectors in css when using specificity?

Tags: css

I have div where i have css class `orcitMultiselectTreeviewHeight` and inside i have another div element that is using `orcitMultiselectTreeview` and inside i have another div that is using class `orcitMultiselectTreeviewTagList`. So i want to target styling for `orcitMultiselectTreeviewTagList`. how can i achieve this task ?

main.css

```
.orcitMultiselectTreeview.orcitMultiselectTreeview .orcitMultiselectTreeviewTagList { 
    max-height: 5em;
    overflow: scroll;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post a snippet of your HTML, it is hard to be sure the exact structure that you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting an element with 2 classes and want to specify both classes there is no space between the selectors. If it is a child then there is a space. Direct child you use `>`

```
<div class="class1 class2">
   <div class="class3">
       <div class="class4">

       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS-

```
.class1.class2 { //selects the base div }
.class1 .class4 { //selects class4 div only }
.class1 > .class4 { //selects no div as class4 is not a child of class1 }
.class1 .class3 .class4 { //selects class4 }
.class1.class2 .class3 > .class4 { //selects class4 as a direct child of class 3 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a typo in your list of selectors, and that it should read:
`.orcitMultiselectTreeviewHeight .orcitMultiselectTreeview .orcitMultiselectTreeviewTagList`

Also, notice the space between each selector, denoting them as children of each.

Comment: another problem when input is 5em scroll should appear that is not happening

Comment: @aftab Can you share the relevant HTML and CSS?

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer to the question. +1.

Answer (score 0):

> So i want to target styling for `.orcitMultiselectTreeviewTagList`. how can I achieve this task ?

If you are using `.orcitMultiselectTreeviewTagList` in many places throughout the document and you want to target this instance alone, the correct selector is:

```
.orcitMultiselectTreeviewHeight .orcitMultiselectTreeview .orcitMultiselectTreeviewTagList {

[STYLES HERE]

}
```

Comment: but i just want to make change on this specific instance we are using this element alot of places

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I have edited the post above to give the correct answer.